# AS3 randomizing an array and comparing it to a string

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, loops, compare

So, I am a basic programmer in flash and this weekend I have to make a small mini game. This is where I get confused...I have 1 movieclip which has 5 labels ( each showing a different shape). I also have a dynamic text field which I have text or (a string) that will need to match the movieclip. Meaning, if the text displays circle, and the shape is circle, if you click the screen you win. if they dont match, you lose. So I am asking this in order to find out, how to create 2 arrays, randomize them then compare the value. I know how to set everything on timers and give scores, I just cant get figure this part out. AS3 and I are having a bad day. Any ideas, even pseudo code helps...or just a flow , something please ! lol thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding randomizing an array, have a look at [this elaborate article](http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-randomly-shuffle-an-array-in-as3/) at Activetuts, which specifically aims at Actionscript. It provides documented code with clear illustrations and tips. You could also check out the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for some pseudo-code.

I don't quite get your question with regards to comparing the strings.. In AS3, you can use `==` to see if the strings are equal.

Comment: allright, that tut helped me figure some things out and led me to realize after using an array like this I can use currentLabel to get the name of my movieclip easily. Thank you Joost. you did more than you know today!